# How do I do source filtering using spring data ReactiveElasticsearch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to do source filtering in my query(i.e `_source`). I'm using the spring data's ReactiveElasticsearch.

I saw that you can obviously do it using the `@Query`. But I want to know if it is available in spring data's elasticsearch client.

Any other approaches to this?

Answer (score 2):

Just adding some code to what Peter said. Below is example on `search-as-you-type` mapping type:

```
final NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery("Elon", "name", "name._2gram", "name._3gram").type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.BOOL_PREFIX));

//include only specific fields
final SourceFilter filter = new FetchSourceFilter(new String[]{"id", "uniqueId", "name", "avatarURL"}, null);

//exclude fields
//final SourceFilter filter = new FetchSourceFilter(new String[]{null, "uniqueId", "avatarURL", "tagline"});

query.addSourceFilter(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Query` interface in Spring Data Elasticsearch has a method `addSourceFilter(SourceFilter sourceFilter)` and all implementations  (`CriteriaQuery`, `StringQuery` and `NativeSearchQuery`) support this.

I just checked the code, the different implementations (transport, rest, reactive rest) use this information from the query.

Comment: But I cant use this with the bootstrapped(i.e. the auto-generated spring data) methods right? (P.S. I am very new to Spring)

Comment: what do you mean with "bootstrapped methods"? Spring Data repository methods?